# htaccess Redirect sub-domain without main page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

Hey guys hope some1 can help me..

I have an old domain (nieuws.please.nl)

i want to redirect 'nieuws.please.nl' to www.please.nl/nieuws-van-en-over-please

but i want to redirect the sub pages like: 'nieuws.please.nl/foo' to www.please.nl/nieuws/foo.

this is what i got:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nieuws\.please\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.please.nl/nieuws/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: this works for redirecting all the sub pages but it also does the main page, tryd alot of thing but cant get it working.

***Please*** help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nieuws\.please\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.please.nl/nieuws-van-en-over-please [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nieuws\.please\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.please.nl/nieuws/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen, the `L` flag should prevent the second condition being applied if the first condition is met

Comment: i dont want to test it live so i used the site : http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Does this site maybe contain a bug or something?

Comment: ... it's more likely the first condition isn't being met. I've updated my answer, assuming that the leading / is possibly not present, I think this might differ by system, so I've added the `?` to indicate the `/` is optional

Comment: How can i buy you a beer!?